# res.on() reading error inside https.get() function javascript api

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, server, requirejs

I am attempting to grab data from an API from openWeatherAPI with a correct api key and query (I checked with Postman to ensure the call is correct), but ran into a syntax error. When I try to call the on() function inside of my https.get callback function, I am met with the following error in my terminal:

```
 response.on("data", (data) => {
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:file-path\api-prac\app.js:16:18)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:693:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:534:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
```

My code:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const app = express()



// what should happen when user tries to go to home page
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=my-api-key";

    https.get(url,  function(req, response) {
        console.log("blah blah repsonse");

        response.on("data", (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            // const weatherDatta = JSON.parse(data)
            /* extra code will be put here to send a response */
        })
    });
    res.send("server is up");
}


app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("app running on server 3000");
})
```

I tried looking at the documentation shown on the https://nodejs.org/api/https.html website, but was unable to find anything that helped outside of what I was already doing with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments for your `https.get()` callback are wrong.  It should be this:

```
 https.get(url,  function(response) {
      response.on('data', ...);
 });
```

There is no second argument so when you try to make one, it's `undefined` and does not work.

Code example in the doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsgeturl-options-callback).

---

Note also that there is no guarantee that you get the entire response in the first `data` event.  The response may arrive in chunks so if you're trying to get the whole response, you should be accumulating all the `data` events and then processing them all in the `end` event.  And, you should be handling errors in multiple places:

```
 https.get(url,  function(response) {
      let result = "";
      response.on('data', data => {
           result += data.toString();
      }).on('end', () => {
           try {
               let weatherData = JSON.parse(result);
               // use the weatherData here
           } catch(e) {
               console.log(e);
               // handle JSON parsing error here
           }
      }).on('error', err => {
           console.log(err);
           // handle http request error here
      });

 });
```

Note, using an http request library such as `got()` or `node-fetch()` or even `fetch()` which is built-in to the newest versions of nodejs will make this code much simpler because they will retrieve the entire response for you and are promise based which makes a number of things including error handling much simpler.

Note how much simpler this is with the `got()` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

```
 got(url).json().then(weatherData => {
      // use weatherData here
 }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      // handler error here
 });
```

Comment: Got it-thank you so much for your help! I was unaware of the libraries you mentioned, and they look like a game-changer.